# chrome.storage.sync save & load functions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, storage

I'm having trouble make a save & load function, here's what I'd like to do :

```
function save(key,val){
    chrome.storage.sync.set({key:val}, function() {});

}

function load(key){
    chrome.storage.sync.get([key], function(result) {return result});
}
```

Problem is, by doing that, my save function really create this in storage : {key: "{"key":"val"}"}

The save takes function literally takes "key", instead of taking it as a parameter.

Also, if I want load tu return my value, I need to do "result.key" instead of "result", but same problem, it takes it literally, it doesn't looks at key as a parameter.

And last problem is, if I place my return here, it doesn't work, and return nothing.

Could anyone help me fix it and understand what I did wrong please ?

ps : thanks for the asynchronous part, it helped a bit, I'll use a callback for the returned value, but it doesn't answer the other problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Use `{[key]: val}`, see [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2274242)

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked, I still got "undefined" when I load

Comment: You need to rework your code as shown in the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: I tried outside of functions, just to test your solution

Comment: it worked with result[key] in the load part